# Flash:AS3, link a URL to a movie clip?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, web, movieclip

I need to be able to click text in my movie and have it take me to a website.
Right now the text is just a movie clip and it slides in from the right.

Thanks in advance :]

Comment: actually, it would be linking a textbox to a url?
sounds sketchy to me, but if you know an easier way to do this, that would be great as well :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the mouse click on the movie clip and send it to the url (B hackish). Or you can use html in a TextField (A if your text field is dynamic), in case you have a static TextField, C.

A Hand cursor will show only over actual link.

```
tf.htmlText = 'Create link with <a href="http://www.example.com">TextField.htmlText</a>';
```

B Hand cursor will show over clip.

```
clip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myBtnClicked);
clip.buttonMode = true;

    function myBtnClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var url:String = "http://www.example.com";
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        try {
            navigateToURL(request, '_blank');
        } catch (e:Error) {
            trace("Error occurred!");
        }
    }
```

C
In the flash IDE, having the textfield instance selected, look into the properties panel, under options you can specify a link for the textfield.

Comment: if it was just simple TLF text, could i substitute that for a button?

for example, could I just put in the instance name of the text 
instead of the instance name of the button?

or do I have to convert the text to a button or something

Comment: I just tried it and I cant click the text, I'm just able to highlight it

Comment: Alright, I did that and It does open up the page if I click the text, but the cursor does not indicate that its a link.

Comment: yes, that happens. Hard to figure out a way to 'hack' something without knowing what is that you have set up there. Use option A if and the cursor will show up, use option B if your text will stay static...there is another option, i will edit the answer.

Comment: well I can send you the movie that I am working on?  Its nothing big at all and its not complex at all, its my first project in flash.  I could email it to you?

Comment: oh it worked!  haha, the thing in the properties box worked :]

thank you so much!

Comment: I feel like there are enough options to find the one that suits you best. Just give a try to them. If you tried B, try to put your textfield inside a movieclip, that should work.

Comment: actually, when I do that the cursor shows that Its a link but it also puts an obnoxious line underneath the text.  Is there any way to get rid of it?

Comment: nevermind.  Adding a link also selects the underline button haha.
my bad, thanks again!